# Sorting Asc/Dsc on JavaNet Beans

Tags: java, sorting, jtable

So My Add Contact Code is like this (using *JTable*)

```
private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();

    if (!NameField.getText().equals("")) {

        model.addRow(new Object[]{
        NameField.getText(),ContactField.getText()});
    } else { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Answer Should Not Be Empty");
    }
```

I need help on how can I sort it. I was searching the whole day and I couldn't find any.

Comment: How do you want to sort your stuff? Writing a comparator is not that difficult and you should be able to find results for that

Comment: I got it already but Thank You :D